# Best practices for referencing columns in a data.frame when writing R packages

Tags: r, dataframe

Why might one prefer using one of the following approaches to reference columns in a data.frame when writing functions inside an R package?

```r
d <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2))

# This is one way to extract a column from a data.frame. 
# Using dollar sign notation
d$x
#> [1] 1 2

# This is another way to extract a column from a data.frame
d[["x"]]
#> [1] 1 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I vaguely remember reading that the second approach is preferable when programming with R, but I don't remember why. The dollar sign approach is more concise, so ceteris paribus, I would rather use the dollar sign approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dollar can work only if we provide the exact column name.  Suppose, if the column name is stored in an object or say

```
d$name(d)[1]
```

or

```
nm1 <- 'x'
d$nm1
```

Instead it would be

```
d[[nm1]]
```

it wouldn't work because it is looking for a literal match

Also, when using the `$`, there is a partial match.  Suppose, we have column names, 'x', 'xx', 'xxy', the 'x' could match either one of them

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you! The dollar sign notation seems pretty ubiquitous, even in very well-established packages. Any idea why that is given the dangers you just outlined?

Comment: @GiovanniColitti packages are written by different people and have their own preferences.  If you know that the name is not going to change or is a constant with no partial matches, you can use `$`